# Is it possible to search a linux kernel queue given the implementation I have?

Tags: c, linux, queue

I am currently trying to search a queue that I have implemented using the linux kernel and get the performance. I am not exactly sure how to go about this, so I am wanting to know if someone can help guide me through it or at list give me some tips on how to do it.

This program is used to test the performance of a queue using the linux kernel. So far I have implemented enqueue and dequeue, but I would like to implement a search function if it is possible using the linux kernel. The solution seems like it would not be difficult, but I am not sure where I should in order to achieve the search functionality that I would like.

```
#include "queue.h"
#include <time.h>
#include <math.h>
/* Create a Queue */
Queue * initQueue(int max)
{
    Queue *Q;
    Q = (Queue *)malloc(sizeof(Queue));
    Q->size = 0;
    Q->capacity = max;
    /* initialize the list head. Kernel list method */
    INIT_LIST_HEAD(&Q->list);
    return Q;
}

/* pop out the queue front, and free the element space */
void dequeue(Queue *Q)
{
    Queue* tmp;
    if(Q->size==0){
    printf("Queue is Empty.\n");
    return;
    }else{
    Q->size--;
    tmp = list_entry(Q->list.next, Queue, list);
    list_del(Q->list.next);
    free(tmp);
    }
}

QueueElement front(Queue *Q)
{
    Queue* first_element;
    struct list_head * first;
    if(Q->size==0){
    printf("Queue is Empty\n");
    exit(0);
    }
    /* find the first element first */
    first = Q->list.next;
    /* reconstruct the first structure */
    first_element = list_entry(first, Queue, list);
    return first_element->e; 
}

QueueElement tail(Queue *Q)
{
    Queue* last_element;
    struct list_head * last;
    if(Q->size==0){
    printf("Queue is Empty.\n");
    exit(0);
    }
    /* find the last element first */
    last = Q->list.prev;
    /* reconstruct the last structure */
    last_element = list_entry(last, Queue, list);
    return last_element->e; 
}

void enqueue(Queue *Q, QueueElement element)
{
    Queue* newQ;
    if(Q->size == Q->capacity){
    printf("Queue is Full. No element added.\n");
    }
    else{
    Q->size++;
    newQ = (Queue*) malloc(sizeof(Queue));
    newQ->e = element;
    /* add to the list tail */
    list_add_tail(&(newQ->list), &(Q->list));
    }
}

static inline long 
time_diff(struct timespec start, struct timespec end)
{
    long diff_in_nano = (end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) * (long) 1e9 + (end.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec);
    return diff_in_nano;
}  

int main(){
int max = 10000000;
    Queue *testQueue = initQueue(max);
    struct timespec start, end;

    //Begin the clock
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &start);
    for(int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {

    enqueue(testQueue,rand());


   }
   //End the clock
   clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &end);

    printf("\033[1;34mTime taken to enqueue 10 million elements into the queue is: %ld us\033[0m\n", (long int)(time_diff(start, end)));

    printf("Front element is %d\n",front(testQueue));
    printf("Last element is %d\n",tail(testQueue));

    //Begin the clock
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &start);

    for(int i = 0; i < 10000000; i++) {
    dequeue(testQueue);
   }
   //End the clock
   clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &end);

   printf("\033[1;34mTime taken to dequeue 10 million elements into the queue is: %ld us\033[0m\n", (long int)(time_diff(start, end)));
  return 0;
}
```

---

list.h `enter code here`

```
/* list.h is copied from Kulesh Shanmugasundaram's site: 
http://isis.poly.edu/kulesh/stuff/src/klist/
Kulesh deserves all the credits for posting the explanation and 
the adapted source code. 
 */

#ifndef __LIST_H
#define __LIST_H

/* This file is from Linux Kernel (include/linux/list.h) 
 * and modified by simply removing hardware prefetching of list items. 
 * Here by copyright, credits attributed to wherever they belong.
 * Kulesh Shanmugasundaram (kulesh [squiggly] isis.poly.edu)
 */

/*
 * Simple doubly linked list implementation.
 *
 * Some of the internal functions ("__xxx") are useful when
 * manipulating whole lists rather than single entries, as
 * sometimes we already know the next/prev entries and we can
 * generate better code by using them directly rather than
 * using the generic single-entry routines.
 */

struct list_head {
    struct list_head *next, *prev;
};

#define LIST_HEAD_INIT(name) { &(name), &(name) }

#define LIST_HEAD(name) \
    struct list_head name = LIST_HEAD_INIT(name)

#define INIT_LIST_HEAD(ptr) do { \
    (ptr)->next = (ptr); (ptr)->prev = (ptr); \
    } while (0)

/*
 * Insert a new entry between two known consecutive entries. 
 *
 * This is only for internal list manipulation where we know
 * the prev/next entries already!
 */
static inline void __list_add(struct list_head *new,
                  struct list_head *prev,
                  struct list_head *next)
{
    next->prev = new;
    new->next = next;
    new->prev = prev;
    prev->next = new;
}

/**
 * list_add - add a new entry
 * @new: new entry to be added
 * @head: list head to add it after
 *
 * Insert a new entry after the specified head.
 * This is good for implementing stacks.
 */
static inline void list_add(struct list_head *new, struct list_head *head)
{
    __list_add(new`enter code here`, head, head->next);
}

/**
 * list_add_tail - add a new entry
 * @new: new entry to be added`enter code here`
 * @head: list head to add it before
 *
 * Insert a new entry before the specified head.
 * This is useful for implementing queues.
 */
static inline void list_add_tail(struct list_head *new, struct list_head *head)
{
    __list_add(new, head->prev, head);
}

/*
 * Delete a list entry by making the prev/next entries
 * point to each other.
 *
 * This is only for internal list manipulation where we know
 * the prev/next entries already!
 */
static inline void __list_del(struct list_head *prev, struct list_head *next)
{
    next->prev = prev;
    prev->next = next;
}

/**
 * list_del - deletes entry from list.
 * @entry: the element to delete from the list.
 * Note: list_empty on entry does not return true after this, the entry is in an undefined state.
 */
static inline void list_del(struct list_head *entry)
{
    __list_del(entry->prev, entry->next);
    entry->next = (void *) 0;
    entry->prev = (void *) 0;
}

/**
 * list_del_init - deletes entry from list and reinitialize it.
 * @entry: the element to delete from the list.
 */
static inline void list_del_init(struct list_head *entry)
{
    __list_del(entry->prev, entry->next);
    INIT_LIST_HEAD(entry); 
}

/**
 * list_move - delete from one list and add as another's head
 * @list: the entry to move
 * @head: the head that will precede our entry
 */
static inline void list_move(struct list_head *list, struct list_head *head)
{
    __list_del(list->prev, list->next);
    list_add(list, head);
}

/**
 * list_move_tail - delete from one list and add as another's tail
 * @list: the entry to move
 * @head: the head that will follow our entry
 */
static inline void list_move_tail(struct list_head *list,
                  struct list_head *head)
{
    __list_del(list->prev, list->next);
    list_add_tail(list, head);
}

/**
 * list_empty - tests whether a list is empty
 * @head: the list to test.
 */
static inline int list_empty(struct list_head *head)
{
    return head->next == head;
}

static inline void __list_splice(struct list_head *list,
                 struct list_head *head)
{
    struct list_head *first = list->next;
    struct list_head *last = list->prev;
    struct list_head *at = head->next;

    first->prev = head;
    head->next = first;

    last->next = at;
    at->prev = last;
}

/**
 * list_splice - join two lists
 * @list: the new list to add.
 * @head: the place to add it in the first list.
 */
static inline void list_splice(struct list_head *list, struct list_head *head)
{
    if (!list_empty(list))
    __list_splice(list, head);
}

/**
 * list_splice_init - join two lists and reinitialise the emptied list.
 * @list: the new list to add.
 * @head: the place to add it in the first list.
 *
 * The list at @list is reinitialised
 */
static inline void list_splice_init(struct list_head *list,
                    struct list_head *head)
{
    if (!list_empty(list)) {
    __list_splice(list, head);
    INIT_LIST_HEAD(list);
    }
}

/**
 * list_entry - get the struct for this entry
 * @ptr:the &struct list_head pointer.
 * @type:the type of the struct this is embedded in.
 * @member:the name of the list_struct within the struct.
 */
#define list_entry(ptr, type, member) \
    ((type *)((char *)(ptr)-(unsigned long)(&((type *)0)->member)))

/**
 * list_for_each-iterate over a list
 * @pos:the &struct list_head to use as a loop counter.
 * @head:the head for your list.
 */
#define list_for_each(pos, head) \
    for (pos = (head)->next; pos != (head); \
     pos = pos->next)
/**
 * list_for_each_prev-iterate over a list backwards
 * @pos:the &struct list_head to use as a loop counter.
 * @head:the head for your list.
 */
#define list_for_each_prev(pos, head) \
    for (pos = (head)->prev; pos != (head); \
     pos = pos->prev)

/**
 * list_for_each_safe-iterate over a list safe against removal of list entry
 * @pos:the &struct list_head to use as a loop counter.
 * @n:another &struct list_head to use as temporary storage
 * @head:the head for your list.
 */
#define list_for_each_safe(pos, n, head) \
    for (pos = (head)->next, n = pos->next; pos != (head); \
     pos = n, n = pos->next)

/**
 * list_for_each_entry-iterate over list of given type
 * @pos:the type * to use as a loop counter.
 * @head:the head for your list.
 * @member:the name of the list_struct within the struct.
 */
#define list_for_each_entry(pos, head, member)\
    for (pos = list_entry((head)->next, typeof(*pos), member);\
    &pos->member != (head); \
     pos = list_entry(pos->member.next, typeof(*pos), member))

/**
 * list_for_each_entry_safe - iterate over list of given type safe against removal of list entry
 * @pos:the type * to use as a loop counter.
 * @n:another type * to use as temporary storage
 * @head:the head for your list.
 * @member:the name of the list_struct within the struct.
 */
#define list_for_each_entry_safe(pos, n, head, member)\
    for (pos = list_entry((head)->next, typeof(*pos), member),\
           n = list_entry(pos->member.next, typeof(*pos), member);\
    &pos->member != (head); \
     pos = n, n = list_entry(n->member.next, typeof(*n), member))


#endif


______________

queue.h 
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#include "list.h"

/* by default, QueueElement is int
 Usage: #define QueueElement <TYPE> */
#ifndef QueueElement
#define QueueElement void*
#endif

typedef struct{
    int capacity;
    int size;
    QueueElement e;
    struct list_head list;
} Queue;

Queue * initQueue(int max);
QueueElement front(Queue *Q);   
QueueElement tail(Queue* Q);
void dequeue(Queue *Q);
void enqueue(Queue *Q, QueueElement element);
```

Comment: To start, `printf()` is not a OS function.  Rather, it is a user function from the C standard library.  Please clarify exactly what your trying to do.  And post the contents of the header file: `queue.h`

Comment: The posted code is missing some needed header files!

Comment: Please post the missing functions, like: `tail()` and `front()`

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding: 1) please consistently indent the code.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces

Comment: before calling `rand()`, there should be a single call to `srand()` to initialize the random number generator

Comment: OT: a header file should not be included unless some of the contents of the file are being used.  Nothing in the `math.h` header file is being used.  Suggest removing the statement: `#include <math.h>`

Comment: OT: regarding: `Q = (Queue *)malloc(sizeof(Queue));`  1) the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code, making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  2) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Comment: what is ` INIT_LIST_HEAD`?

Comment: regarding the call to `exit(0)` in the function: `front()` why exit the program?

Comment: Please post the contents of the function: `list_entry()`